# Parsing all possible UTF-8 values in a json string

Tags: javascript, json, utf-8

How can I get the following to run without the unexpected token error?

I would like to parse any possible utf-8 in a JSON string.  Since characters like \u0000 (null) are valid UTF-8 I should be able to parse them in a json string right?

```
s='{"body": "\u0000"}'
JSON.parse(s)
```

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token  in JSON at position 10

I get the same error using `JSON.parse(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)))`.

Here is a larger sample from the data set:

```
\u0000\u0001\u0002\u0003\u0004\u0005\u0006\a\b\t\n
!\"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?
ΣΤΥΦΧΨΩΪΫάέήίΰαβγδεζηθικλμνξοπρςστυφχψωϊϋόύ
```

Comment: Maybe you meant `s='{"body": "\\u0000"}'`? JSON should not contain nul characters.

Comment: What browser did you test this on? Also does your JSON actually contain `\u0000` (which would in most cases requires you to have typed `\\u0000`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use double reverse solidus and it's good to go. Such as:

```
s=`{"body": "\\u0000"}`
JSON.parse(s)
```

or

```
s=`{"body": "\\t"}`
JSON.parse(s)
```